# Rails 3 mail not working, however devise mail does works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, centos, actionmailer

I have a rails 3.2.3 application that works fine and delivers devise's created mail messages as, registration confirmation and password forget mail messages to set a new password.

However I have a different places that I want to deliver mail notifications.

This is my `Notifier`model.

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@domain.com"
  default to: "admin@domain.com"

  def new_post_submitted(post)
    @post = post
    mail(subject: "Anúncio enviado: #{@post.title}")
  end

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(subject: "Mensagem de contato: #{@message.subject}")
  end

end
```

and the controller calls:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid?
    Notifier.new_message(@message).deliver
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Obrigado. Sua Mensagem enviada com sucesso")
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Por favor preencha todos os campos."
    render :new
  end
end
```

The log output says it was delivered:

```
Started POST "/contato" for 187.57.102.168 at 2012-08-31 11:28:51 +0900
Processing by ContactController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TVdmDYCA4x3JVi+9pMcpY7OSU/P1lE9enLiFJlK9W1M=", "message"=>{"name"=>"kleber", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "subject"=>"teste", "body"=>"hello there"}, "commit"=>"Enviar"}
  Rendered notifier/new_message.html.erb (0.1ms)

Sent mail to admin@domain.com (152ms)
Redirected to http://www.domain.com/
Completed 302 Found in 158ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And the following configuration on my `config/production.rb`file.

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "localhost",
  :port => 25,
  :domain => "domain.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name  => "admin@domain.com",
  :password  => "mypassword",
  :enable_starttls_auto => false
}
```

Any clue on what is happening here?

Comment: have you checked your spam emails?

Comment: and the system log folder? (/var/log, i.e.  /var/log/mail.log ) any warning/error there?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the settings that work in my production.rb file.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => 'mail.domain.com',
   :port => 587,
   :domain => 'domain.com',
   :authentication => :login,
   :user_name => 'postmaster@domain.com',
   :password => 'password'
  }
```

Not sure you have to specify delivery_method?

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I don't have that in my config and everything works properly.

In the rails API http://api.rubyonrails.org/ ActionMailer section there is an option to set a delivery error.

```
raise_delivery_errors - Whether or not errors should be raised if the email fails to be delivered.
```

You could try that to further troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you haven't turned off deliveries somewhere else in the environment file:

```
# the default is true anyway, so if you don't see it anywhere in
# the file, you should be okay
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I would next try changing the delivery method to either `:sendmail` or `:file`. If you have sendmail installed and configured on your system (at least a development system), then you should receive the e-mails you send. I was surprised at one point to discover that sendmail worked out of the box on OS X. I'm not sure if you'd find the same on CentOS.

If you don't have sendmail or don't want to configure it, use the `:file` delivery method to dump the e-mails to a file on the filesystem.

At this point, if the e-mails don't deliver via sendmail or file, you know there's a problem further up the stack. If they do deliver, then the problem is your SMTP configuration. Try using a known working SMTP server (such as your Gmail account). If that works, then you know it's a problem with the SMTP server running on localhost and not with ActionMailer.